# reading the current url of a tab

Tags: javascript, url

I need to read the browsers URL (specefic to the tab) using javascript. I tried the

```
var currentURL = window.location; 
alert(currentURL.href) ;
```

It shows `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` instead of the web address. 
What should I do to get the web address?

Can someone please help me out with this.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean in the firefox extensions?

Comment: window.location.href doesn't work?

Comment: +1 for @Greg K : you should have written this in Answer :)

Comment: yes @mark. its to be implemented in firefox extensions

Comment: @Webbisshh I didn't post as an answer because I wasn't sure if the op was writing a plugin.

Comment: javascript:alert(document.location); works for me.

Answer (score 2):

document.location.href OR window.location.href must work !!

Comment: no @webbish! document.location.href or window.location.href gives me the following :
chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
this is the chrome url. What i need is the external Http URL! 
any suggestions on wer i mite be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably already got the answer to this, but simply using document.URL will get you the tab's URL.

javascript:(alert(document.URL))